# Why won't my Skeleton deal damage to my player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-engine

So, every time the skeleton hit the player/character. It won't show the word "HIT!". What did I do wrong?

[THE PLAYER IMAGE INSPECTOR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebtm6.jpg)

[THE SKELETON IMAGE INSPECTOR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP01t.jpg)

[THE HIERARCHY IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtNry.jpg)

---

---

**SKELETON ENEMY SCRIPT**

---

---

```
private Rigidbody2D myBody;

[Header("Movement")]
public float moveSpeed;
private float minX, maxX;
public float distance;
public int direction;

private bool patrol, detect;

private Transform playerPos;
private Animator anim;

[Header("Attack")]
public Transform attackPos;
public float attackRange;
public LayerMask playerLayer;
public int damage;

//sound
```

**VOID AWAKE**

```
void Awake()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    playerPos = GameObject.Find("George").transform;
    myBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
```

**VOID START**

```
private void Start()
{
    maxX = transform.position.x + (distance);
    minX = maxX - distance;

    //if (Random.value > 0.5) direction = 1;
    //else direction = -1;
}
```

**VOID UPDATE**

```
void Update()
{
    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, playerPos.position) <= 4.0f) patrol = false;
    else patrol = true;
}
```

**VOID FIXED UPDATE**

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (anim.GetBool("Death"))
    {
        myBody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false;
        myBody.isKinematic = true;
        anim.SetBool("Attack", false);
        return;
    }


    if (myBody.velocity.x > 0)
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(1f, transform.localScale.y);
        anim.SetBool("Attack", false);
    }
    else if
        (myBody.velocity.x < 0) transform.localScale = new Vector2(-1f, transform.localScale.y);


    if (patrol)
    {
        detect = false;
        switch (direction)
        {
            case -1:
                if (transform.position.x > minX)
                    myBody.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, myBody.velocity.y);
                else
                    direction = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                if (transform.position.x < maxX)
                    myBody.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, myBody.velocity.y);
                else
                    direction = -1;
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Vector2.Distance(playerPos.position, transform.position) >= 1.0f)
        {
            if (!detect)
            {
                detect = true;
                anim.SetTrigger("Detect");
                myBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, myBody.velocity.y);
            }
            if (anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Detect")) return;



            Vector3 playerDir = (playerPos.position - transform.position).normalized;

            if (playerDir.x > 0)
                myBody.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed + 0.4f, myBody.velocity.y);
            else
                myBody.velocity = new Vector2(-(moveSpeed + 0.4f), myBody.velocity.y);
        }
        else if (Vector2.Distance(playerPos.position, transform.position) <= 1.0)
        {
            myBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, myBody.velocity.y);
            anim.SetBool("Attack", true);
        }
    }
}
```

**VOID ATTACK**

```
 public void Attack()
    {
        myBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, myBody.velocity.y);

        Collider2D attackPlayer = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(attackPos.position, attackRange, playerLayer);

        if (attackPlayer == null)
        {
            if(attackPlayer.tag == "Player")
            {
                print("Hit!");
                attackPlayer.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().TakeDamage(damage);
            }
        }
    }
    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(attackPos.position, attackRange);
    }
```

---

---

**PLAYER HEALTH SCRIPT**

---

---

**VOID AWAKE**

```
 public int health = 100;

    void Awake()
    {

    }
```

**VOID UPDATE**

```
 void Update()
    {
        if (health < 1)
        {
            print("Dead");
        }    
    }
```

**VOID TAKE DAMAGE**

```
 public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        FindObjectOfType<CameraShake>().ShakeItMedium();
        health -= damage;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target)
    {
        if(target.tag == "Fireball")
        {
            TakeDamage(25);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please turn this into a [mcve] there is a lot of code there, and other than "its not working" theres too much for people to wade through, and links are generally less approved.

Comment: I'm still new to this page but I will try doing it! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont seem to call the "Attack" method in your script.

```
else if (Vector2.Distance(playerPos.position, transform.position) <= 1.0)
{
    myBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, myBody.velocity.y);
    // calling the attack method, so the physics cast is being made
    Attack();
    anim.SetBool("Attack", true);
}
```

And dont forget to change this, you are checking if the cast hit nothing instead of something.

```cs
// if the cast hit something
if (attackPlayer != null)
{
    if(attackPlayer.tag == "Player")
    {
        print("Hit!");
        attackPlayer.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().TakeDamage(damage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While there maybe many other things wrong with that long pile of code:

`if (attackPlayer == null)
        {
            if(attackPlayer.tag == "Player")
            {
                print("Hit!");
                attackPlayer.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().TakeDamage(damage);
            }
        }`

You check if attackPlayer is null and then try do work on it... Im pretty you sure you meant `if (attackPlayer != null)`...

Comment: I tried adding "!=" to the attack if statement but for some reason, it still does not work.

Comment: Where exactly do you trigger the attack function from